# MongoDB: bulk update to insert missing parts

Tags: mongodb

I need to update all documents in MongoDB by a "default values" document: if any part of "default values" doesn't exist in DB documents - add this part, otherwise don't modify this part.

I tried to accomplish this by stored functions: load doc, update it recursively, save it.

insertDefValues.js:

```
db.system.js.save({_id: "DoInsertDefValues", value: function(data, defValues) 
{
    var modified = false;
    for (var prop in defValues)
    {
        if (data[prop] === undefined)
        {
            data[prop] = defValues[prop];
            modified = true;
        }            
        else if (typeof defValues[prop] === "object")
            modified |= DoInsertDefValues(data[prop], defValues[prop]);
    }
    return modified;
}});

db.system.js.save({_id: "InsertDefValues", value: function() 
{
    var defValues = {
        //...
    };
    var docs = db.collection.find();
    docs.forEach(function(data)
    {
        if (DoInsertDefValues(data, defValues))
            db.collection.save(data);
    });
}});

db.loadServerScripts();
InsertDefValues();
```

And then I execute it by mongo shell:

```
mongo collection insertDefValues.js
```

The problem is this approach is too slow (30 secs on 2K docs on test data, production DB is much bigger). I use MongoDB 2.4.10 which doesn't have Bulk updates so this is not an option. I'm going to try to generate series of updates, something like:

E.g. for "default values": `{"1": {"2": "blah"}}`

updates:

```
db.collection.update({"1": {$exists: false}}, {$set: {"1": {"2": "blah"}}})
db.collection.update({"1.2": {$exists: false}}, {$set: {"1.2": "blah"}})
```

Is there any other options?

"Default values" doc is 7KB compact JSON, no string values.
Average size of collection doc is 10KB of compact JSON.

I can use MongoDB-CSharp driver if it can produce significantly faster solution (I doubt it).

Comment: Hm, if a value doesn't exist in a document, it evaluates to `null`. So you could use your model / DAOs to return the default value if the field is `null`. Easier to change in the future, and less unnecessary data stored to disk.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I'm storing C# structures by a generated serializer. I'd like to store default values (includes C# inline initializers and values assigned in constructors) explicitely except C# "native" default values (default(T)) to avoid accidental implicit change of saved data when initialization logic changed. Also I wouldn't like to store default values separatly from data structure definition.

Answer (score 1):

I find something in your code and maybe they're errors.

**InsertDefValues**`(data, defValues);` should be **DoInsertDefValues**`(data, defValues);`, right?

The **modified** in **DoInsertDefValues** isn't returned and checked before save, which means you will save every document, right?

The scripts are executed at mongo shell - client side, which may will low performance because receiving data from server and handling something for connection socket for every save operation. I learned these actions from mongodb driver for java, if mongo shell with same principle as other drivers, this will be the main reason to low performance. Call `db.eval` to let scripts executed at server side if the collection hasn't been sharded. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by generating recursive updates (as described in the question). Execution time dropped from 30 secs to 0.5 sec.

Comment: May I know what is your `generating recursive updates` to make that big progress?

Comment: @Wizard: "Series of updates" as I briefly described in the question. Maybe the biggest difference is what you mentioned in your answer: most execution happens on server side reducing shell-server communication. I'll try db.eval to compare results.